# Move 1st div up and reveal text (2nd div) while hovering over 1st div

Tags: html, css

My problem is a div that has to move up while hovering over it.
Check [this JSfiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Barq/efA9V/2/).

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the right div is the hovered one. In the jsfiddle I took 1 div which I'm trying to achieve the hover effect on, but I just don't get it.

I tried this:

```
.service-bg:hover + .service-content-bg {
    background-position:0 -250px;
}
```

But nothing happens.

Can anyone please help me?
I'm not very experienced with this kind of css level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't need the `+` as `.service-content-bg` is a child of `.service-bg`

```
.service-bg:hover .service-content-bg {
    background-position:0 -250px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efA9V/3/)

To then show the hidden text you need to add the following CSS

```
.service-bg:hover .service-hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efA9V/7/)

Comment: Wow, great! Ok so now the background moved up, but the rest wasn't moved up like the image showed. Is that done in the same way?

Comment: Thanks you are my hero!

Comment: I got it working now: http://jsfiddle.net/Barq/efA9V/9/
Only one question remains: is it possible to smooth this effect a bit?
Like something similar to this: http://demos.xiaothemes.com/rudermann/portfolios/portfolio-grid-4/

Comment: Nevermind, got it myself!

added:
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;